# Python Pandas - select dataframe columns where equals

Tags: python, pandas

What is the Pandas equivalent of this SQL code?

```
Select id, fname, lname from table where id = 123
```

I know that this is the equivalent of an SQL 'where' clause in Pandas:

```
df[df['id']==123]
```

And this selects specific columns:

```
df[['id','fname','lname']]
```

But I can't figure out how to combine them. All examples I've seen online select all columns with conditions. I want to select a limited number of columns with one or more conditions.

Comment: `df.loc`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: `df.loc[df['id']==123, ['id','fname','lname']]`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use SQL-like `.query()` method:

```
df.query("id == 123")[['id','fname','lname']]
```

or

```
df[['id','fname','lname']].query("id == 123")
```

or more "Pandaic":

```
df.loc[df['id'] == 123, ['id','fname','lname']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on @MaxU's answer, suppose you needed multiple column values, taking 'fname'

```
df[['id','fname','lname']].query("fname == ('simon', 'michael')")
```

Without using query method of @MaxU, for simplicity included all columns:

```
df[df.fname.isin(['simon', 'michael'])]
```

Cascading the above with [['id','fname','lname']] will give the needed answer.